# Reopen a question on the imputability of God

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/41632/12563) on whether God can be considered to have a share in the praise or blame due to our deeds, given that he has created us as we are, was closed in its original form on 5 July - I voted to close as "too broad".

Subsequently, after discussions with the original poster, I significantly edited the question, rephrasing certain parts, focusing the inquiry, and specifically requesting an overview of [at least the top few] major approaches to the question. I then voted to re-open.

Is there anything else I can do to improve the question?

Comment: 3 vtr's, one of them mine. Why the meta post when it looks like the edit and nomination for reopening is getting it done?

Comment: What else can you do? Delete/flag obsolete comments.

Comment: It was just taking a while. I'm impatient I guess.

Comment: Three days passed between your edits and the reopening. I don't know if that's generally considered short or long, but I just thought that could be a useful data point for someone who _does_ know (@fredsbend?)

Comment: My advice: get rid of the word imputable. I gather that it's used in Catholicism, but in normal English it just doesn't make sense to ask whether God is imputable.

Comment: Also how is it different from all the other theodicy questions?

Comment: @curiousdannii it's not at all a theodicy question. It's not asking why there is pain and suffering. It's asking whether God can be praised or blamed, at least partly, for our deeds, and if so why we get judged for them, not God.

Comment: Imputable does have a standard English definition, but I'm not sure what to change it to. Hm.

Comment: @MattGutting "**It's asking whether God can be praised or blamed**" Asking whether God can be blamed is the core issue of theodicy!

Comment: @curiousdannii The core issue of theodicy, as I've always experienced it, is whether God is good. Whether He's to be blamed is a different issue. This question asks about the extent to which God is morally responsible for our decisions.

Comment: @MattGutting God's involvement in our choices and acts is only so contentious because of our sin. We question whether God is good because of the idea that he might be responsible for our sinful decisions. It may be slightly indirect, but I think it's definitely still a theodicy question.

Comment: @curiousdannii I think we may need to agree to disagree on that one :-)

Comment: @curiousdannii I thought about it being a theodicy question when I edited it for tags recently, and to make it a bit more on-topic (because I think someone flagged it for closure). However, I think I agree with Matt that theodicy is about God doing something about all the pain and suffering. Whether God is moral or not is related, but not the core issue of theodicy. Perhaps the tag would be helpful there. Removing "imputability" was a good idea. It reads much better now.

Comment: @Mr.Beatitude I think three days is about normal. Closures seem to come more quickly than reopens. Makes some sense. Further, I find that to get a question reopened, you can't usually depend solely on the nomination and review queue. Meta posts and favor requests in chat usually help.

Comment: @fredsbend Theodicy's etymology comes from "justifying God". Now I know we can't rely on etymology to determine current meaning, but I've always understood it to be a broader topic than purely about how he can allow evils to exist. But it doesn't really matter. I only brought it up because I thought there's a distinct possibility this might be a dupe of an existing question. I haven't looked for one, but if we find one we agree on then a dupe it would be, no matter the terminology.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, you'll have to find the dupe first.